# VS2017 Cross Platform IntelliSense not work

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017

On a cross platform project vs2017 copies the include directory from the remote host to the local host.

In my case i use wsl ubuntu as host and want to develop a c++ application, the include directory on the host system is on:

> \usr\include\c++\7

Terminal output from this path and command ls -l

> drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Oct 17 21:47 7
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1 Jul 26 14:25 7.3.0 -> 7

when i connect me the first time to the host system vs2017 tries to copy the include directories from remote host to local host. The path where vs2017 stores the files is here:

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\...

My problem is, vs2017 onyl copies the folders but not the content (no headers).
For exampel in the folder on the host there is the file:

> iostream

On my local machine i found in the vs2017 cach th following folder which also have a folder called "7":

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-629654356\usr\include\c++\7
>
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-629654356\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\c++\7
>
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0\-629654356\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-linux-gnu

But all three folders only have subfolders, there are no header files!!
So what can i do, to get the conetent.

The rest of the project work fine (build the project remote with make file) only IntelliSense isnt working because of the missing include files.